# jquery mobile with FRAMEs and inner frame with scroll bar

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

```
    i have used nested frames, 

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>


    </head>


    <frameset rows="200px,500px">

    <frame src="topBar.html" > <!-- top frame -->
    <frameset cols="30%,70%">
        <frame src="leftBar.php" noresize /> <!-- left frame-->

       <frame src="rightBar.php" name="rightBar"  id="rightBar" frameborder="yes"  style="overflow:scroll"/> <!-- left frame-->  <!-- right frame-->

     </frameset>
     </frameset>

    </html>


the rightBar.php is

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
<link href="jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="style/jquery.mobile.scrollview.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile.scrollview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- This reference to phonegap.js will allow for code hints as long as the current site has been configured as a mobile application. 
     To configure the site as a mobile application, go to Site -> Mobile Applications -> Configure Application Framework... -->
<script src="/phonegap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#page').scroll();

    var data = 'cat=drinks' ;
    $.ajax
        (

            {
                url:'rgh.php',
                type: "POST",
                data:data,

                success: function (data)
                {       

                $("#loadContent").html(data);

                }
            }
        )

        $(".closeBtn").click(function(){            
            $(".QTPopup").css('display', 'none');
        })
});
</script>
</head> 
<body> 



<div data-role="page" id="page" data-rel="dialog"  data-transition="pop">

    <div data-role="content" data-position="fixed"> 

        <ul data-role="listview" id="loadContent"  data-filter="true"  data-scroll="true">



        </ul>       
    </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

when user clicks the leftBar.php 's options it reflects on rightBar.php and shows the content dynamically, the browser shows the Scroll Bar only for rightBar frame which is fine on PC, but it is not showing on Android device, it shows whole scroll bar to webview, i need only rightBar frame to show scroll-bar in Android webview ? so can anyone help me ?

Comment: ithe ye http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19827/casual-marathi-chat